# SMTPSenderRefused at /users/password-reset/ (530, b'5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at\n5.5.1 https://support.google.com/ma

Tags: django

I am getting this error while sending mail using django.
/usr/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py in sendmail, line 867
/usr/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py in sendmail
            raise SMTPSenderRefused(code, resp, from_addr)

tried mailjet also same issues

Comment: Can you show your settings file?

Answer (score 1):

If your are using Google SMTP make sure you have the following settings set in your settings.py file:

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'user emailid'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
```

Also make sure you are logged in with gmail with the provided email id and password in your machine.
Also you need to enable access for less secure apps in your Google account. Here is the link to help you change your Google Account configuration settings [link](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6260879?hl=en)

Comment: Yes I did that But Still Having an issue

Comment: I am doing it in deployment so I have actually hosted it

Answer (score 1):

If you saved your email/password in environ variable for the first time. Please close your terminal and open it again, I hope this will solve your problem. I have run into the same problem and solved issues just like this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create app password via your google account.
You can't use your email address to send mail.
Go to this link: https://myaccount.google.com/security

Answer (score 0):

For me the error was caused by:

```
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.getenv('EMAIL_HOST_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.getenv('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD')
```

as the env variables where not correctly imported.

Also remember to enable access for less secure apps in your Google account.

Answer (score 0):

Your users must be active and have valid e-mail.
Go here `https://myaccount.google.com/security`, press on `app password` and gererate 16-symbolic password and put it to settings.

And use it in settings.py:

```python
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'put here your email-address with 16-symbolic password'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'put here your 16-symbols symbolic'
```